# Is it possible to create a responsive web page using html5 only? (without css or javascript)

Tags: html, responsive-design

Let me know how to achieve this if it's possible to do so using HTML5 only.

I've done all of my responsive design using CSS with media queries. I'm currently working on a template displayed inside an editor and the customer wanted it to be mobile friendly. The problem is I can't include any css or javascript files inside that editor and so wonder if there's any possible way to achieve that

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've done all of my responsive design using CSS with media queries. I'm currently working on a template displayed inside an editor and the customer wanted it to be mobile friendly. The problem is I can't include any css or javascript files inside that editor and so wonder if there's any possible way to achieve that.

Comment: @WombleGold you can do it without CSS technically. But not without "styles". And definitely not without both CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: @jessie What is this 'editor' you speak of, and why can't you add CSS to it?

Comment: @WombleGold Do you mean the inline styles? Of course, I applied some inline styles to make it responsive to some extent. But I can't use the style rules like medias with those inline styles and so some pictures that should be displayed differently for desktop and mobile do not look good. Do you have a better idea for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: @jessie If you can't use media queries and can't add JS, it's going to be hard to have different layout for mobile. You'd have to be very clever with percentages in your inline styles to achieve this

Comment: @azium It's kinda a WYSIWYG editor where a user can edit the html templates and generate pdf after editing. It worked fine with larger devices but not look good with mobile devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't build responsive web page without using css
for responsive web page create css with

```
@media screen and (min-width: 737px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  /*  write CSS element */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
}

@media (min-width:768px){
}
```

**for example write media specific css like**

```
@media (min-width:768px){.para{font-size:21px}}

@media (min-width:992px){.container{width:970px}}

@media (min-width:1200px){.container{width:1170px}}

@media screen and (max-width:767px){

.table-responsive{width:100%;margin-bottom:10px;overflow-y:hidden;-ms-overflow-style:-ms-autohiding-scrollbar;border:2px solid #ddd
}
```

[programming tutorials](http://tutorialsflow.com/)